# Add custom field to Woocommerce add new attribute / edit page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Is there a way to add a custom field to the add new attribute page or edit attribute in Woocommerce ?

Preferably with CMB2, but whatever works.

[image: Woocommerce attributes page]

As I understand, this specific section of woocommerce is a taxonomy inception - it's a taxonomy that creates taxonomies :)

I looked under woocommerce/includes/class-wc-post-types.php but not sure what filter would do the trick (if any).

I've managed to add fields to the individual terms but I need a field for the attribute itself.

Comment: using 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' and 'woocommerce_after_edit_attribute_fields' actions, i've managed to output a field on the add / edit pages, don't know how to save / load the value from the database

Comment: Did my answer help or you needed more details? :)

Comment: Yes, thanks! I ended up creating a function to generate multiple fields in case i needed, but basically doing what you suggested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can add custom fields to WooCommerce (product) attributes, which are WordPress custom taxonomies — e.g. an attribute named *Color* creates a taxonomy with the slug `pa_color`.

But because the data are stored in [the `woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies` table](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Database-Description#table-woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies) which does not offer a field for custom data, you'll need to save your data somewhere else, e.g. the WordPress options table (`wp_options`) like what I did in the examples below:

#### Add "My Field" to the attribute form:

```php
function my_edit_wc_attribute_my_field() {
    $id = isset( $_GET['edit'] ) ? absint( $_GET['edit'] ) : 0;
    $value = $id ? get_option( "wc_attribute_my_field-$id" ) : '';
    ?>
        <tr class="form-field">
            <th scope="row" valign="top">
                <label for="my-field">My Field</label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input name="my_field" id="my-field" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_attribute_fields', 'my_edit_wc_attribute_my_field' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_edit_attribute_fields', 'my_edit_wc_attribute_my_field' );
```

#### Set/save the "My Field" value, e.g. in the options table:

```php
function my_save_wc_attribute_my_field( $id ) {
    if ( is_admin() && isset( $_POST['my_field'] ) ) {
        $option = "wc_attribute_my_field-$id";
        update_option( $option, sanitize_text_field( $_POST['my_field'] ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_attribute_added', 'my_save_wc_attribute_my_field' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_attribute_updated', 'my_save_wc_attribute_my_field' );
```

#### Delete the custom option when the attribute is deleted.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_attribute_deleted', function ( $id ) {
    delete_option( "wc_attribute_my_field-$id" );
} );
```

Then for example, on a taxonomy/term archive page, you can get the My Field value like so:

```php
$term = get_queried_object();
$attr_id = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name( $term->taxonomy );
$my_field = get_option( "wc_attribute_my_field-$attr_id" );
```

Comment: Great answer Sally CJ, How can i do for an upload file field? thanks in advanced.

Comment: The bit you need to change is my_save_wc_attribute_my_field, where you'll have to accept the file upload instead - and probably save it to disk or the media library and put a filename or ID in the options table rather than store all the data there.

Comment: @Sally CJ How can I display field value on product page?

Comment: @Juraj as long as you know the attribute ID, which is the `attribute_id` value in the `woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies` table, you can use `get_option()` to get the field value no matter where are you displaying it. If you don't already know the attribute ID, but you know the attribute name (which is a taxonomy like `pa_color`), you can use `wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name()` to get the attribute ID. Anyway, have a look at [this example](https://gist.github.com/5ally/d5e5d2588a3e11f0f6f0ba071ef1a323).

Comment: @JuaneteMontoya @Rup back then, I didn't check this, but today I found out that I had to manually add the [`enctype` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype) to the product attribute form, hence I made an example [here](https://gist.github.com/5ally/0b852d5a4104b1eca069e945e4ded71f) which adds a field labeled "My Image Field" ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THLOK.png)).